# DataList not appearing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having trouble displaying a DataList in a aspx page.

```
protected void btnAdminExecuteQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataAdapter _SqlDA;
    try
    {
        _SqlConnection.Open();
        _SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(txtBoxAdminQuery.Text, _SqlConnection);
        _SqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(_SqlCommand);
        DataSet _SqlDS = new DataSet();
        _SqlDA.Fill(_SqlDS);
        _SqlConnection.Close();
        DL.DataSource = _SqlDS.Tables[0];
        DL.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (this._SqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            this._SqlConnection.Close();
        }
        txtBoxAdminErrorMsg.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

I'm sure the ConnectionString and command are correct because I've tested them, and I can see in the debugger that the DataList has rows, it has Data but it's just not displaying.
This is what I see when I execute the query on the 'Admin Panel'

[image]

HTML:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxAdminQuery" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAdminExecuteQuery" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdminExecuteQuery_Click" Text="Execute Query" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxAdminErrorMsg" runat="server" Enabled="False" Height="68px" ReadOnly="True" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="463px"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="_SqlDS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CompanyConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Accounts]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:DataList ID="DL" runat="server" CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1" RepeatColumns="2">
        </asp:DataList>

    </div>
</form>
```

My goal is to run custom queries and display the results in the DataList, I know how to configure the DataList through Visual Studio Designer, but if I do it from there the Query is static I can't change it, as far as I know.

Proving that the _SqlDS has data:
[image]

Comment: Share your HTML too that will be more helpful.

Comment: Have you ever debug your code and check your `_SqlDS` _really_ has a table and it _really_ has data?

Comment: You know that you have created a sql-injection workbench? Everyone using your tool is invited to destroy your database.

Comment: Shared HTML.
Yes debugged and checked that _SqlDS really has table and data.
Yes I know I created a SQL-Injection-vulnerable workbench but this is just to get this thing to work, I don't use this for the main site, this isn't public yet.

Comment: You haven't set `DataKeyField` and `DataMember` properties in your `DataList`.

Comment: There isn't any `TemplateFields` in your `DataList` how do you expect to populate them?

Comment: What am I supposed to set them to, though?

Comment: this line scares me _SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(txtBoxAdminQuery.Text, _SqlConnection); sqlinjection written all over.

Comment: There is no any autogeneratecolumn property on datalist. can you try to loop through the columns and add it. check the link http://forums.asp.net/t/936960.aspx?DataList+AutoGenerated+Columns

Comment: Okay I understand that I have to add the columns manually, thank you!
@Harry it's an Admin panel only usable by me.

Comment: @KD I have no idea how to add the columns to the DataList.Controls...

Comment: hope this link will help you to do so. http://forums.asp.net/t/1310596.aspx?How+to+add+column+in+datalist+at+design+time

Comment: Ran across that link before, it adds it in HTML, I'm looking to do that in C#.
Still looking of course.